# python pandas: I've got an error that occurs in the line I used drop function

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I started to learn machine learning and I'm learning it following some guy on youtube. 
Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g4O5UOH304&t=1684s
So basically, it's same code as how he wrote.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

#print(data.head())
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]
print(data.head())
predict = "G3"

x = np.array(data.drop([predict]), axis=1)
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)
```

And when I run this..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asb46/PycharmProjects/tensorEnv/lec1.py", line 14, in <module>
    x = np.array(data.drop([predict]), axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\asb46\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3697, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\asb46\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3111, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\asb46\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3143, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\asb46\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4404, in drop
    '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['G3'] not found in axis"
```

I'm using pandas: 0.23.4 version. I tried downgrade, but still error occurs... I don't know 
what is the right version for my code.

Comment: `x = np.array(data.drop([predict], axis=1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change to the code will fix this.

Instead of

```
x = np.array(data.drop([predict]), axis=1)
```

Do

```
x = np.array(data.drop([predict], axis=1))
```

Explanation: axis is an argument for drop method and not for np.array